# Does there exist a Lebesgue measurable set $[0,1] \subset D$ such that $D \neq [0,1]$ and $\lambda ^{*} (D) = 1$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Question is in the title. I've tried examples to show there is such a $D$ but not had any luck, and a proof that there is no such $D$ doesn't seem to go anywhere.

Comment: Why not $D=[0,1]\cup\{2\}$?

Comment: Thank you for accepting my stupidity @MikeEarnest